# Why My ternery operator is having the Opposite effect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-rendering

i have been trying to get my ternery operator to work on a nested fashion on the link component of the router. appearently the ternery operator is flipped where its supposed to be like
Condition?true:false
mine is like Condition?false:true which is really confusing since i want to nest the ternery ot have mulitple cases like a switch statemnt to make the button react to what every component its put on

i have attached some code in order to make it more clearer

```
function BottomNav({product}) {
   

  return (
<div className="bottomNav">
    <Link to={product !== 'model 3'? '/design/model3':'/design/model'}>
      <button className="leftbutton">Custom design</button>
    </Link>
```

the above takes a props called product and checks the product name to give a certain route for the specific product

Comment: What evidence or proof do you have that *your* version of Javascript is not applying the correct ternary logic? What debugging details can you provide? Are you saying that when `product` is `"model 3"` and the condition is `"model 3" !== "model 3"` (*which evaluates false*)  that the link navigates to `"/design/model3"` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to compare `product` and `'model 3'`. Here let assume we get value in `product` as `'model 2'` so in condition it will looks like this:

```
'model 2' !== 'model 3'
```

It will return you result as `true` so first condition `'/design/model3'` will trigger. If we get value in `product` as `'model 3'` so in condition it will look like this:

```
'model 3' !== 'model 3'
```

So which looks obviously false so it will trigger second condition `'/design/model'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want nested ternary operators. Here is an example:

```
product === 'model 3' ? '/design/model3' :
   product === 'model 4' ? '/design/model4' :
     product === 'model 5' ? '/design/model5' : '/design/modeldefault'
```